# Adding any sort of Math to a Money field in a CRM Report returns #error

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I've got a report in Dynamics CRM 2011 that I'm trying to construct that requires a money field to have some maths applied to it.

```
=Fields!new_entity.new_moneyfield.Value
```

works fine

```
=Fields!new_entity.new_moneyfield.Value*2
```

returns #Error

WTH am I missing?

Comment: OMG I can't believe I've been stumped on this for half a day.

    =Fields!new_entity.new_moneyfieldValue.Value*2
Is the answer. The reporting interface sets up two versions of the money field, the version I was using is a text representation of the value and the version that works is the numerical version.

Love the intuitiveness of that.

Comment: if you've solved your own issue, perhaps you might consider closing your question.